# Ads resources are detected to be as Blocked Resources

Tags: google-search-console, error

I don't understand this part of the Google Webmaster. I am wondering why google is blocking this resources which come from Ads(as I understand)? I know it is beyond the power on the site robots.txt to fix this but I just want to know how can I able to fix or just minimize the error on it.

Is it has something to do with Google Ads?

Here is the screenshot: https://ibb.co/huQVAk

Answer (score 1):

Google is not blocking anything, your ad partners are via their `robots.txt` or using `noindex`. For example: `http://adx.adform.net/robots.txt`. What this means is that the ad will not be included in the indexing or cache of your page, its pretty common and nothing to worry about.